# Hibernate mapping to a common table

Tags: hibernate

this is my doctor entity

```
@Entity
public class Doctor implements java.io.Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer id;

private String firstName;

@OneToMany
private List<Status>status=new ArrayList<Status>();

@Embedded
private Chamber chamber;


public List<Status> getStatus() {
    return status;
 }

 public void setStatus(List<Status> status) {
    this.status = status;
 }

public Chamber getChamber() {
    return chamber;
}

public void setChamber(Chamber chamber) {
    this.chamber = chamber;
}

public Doctor() {
}

public Integer getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return this.firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}


 }
```

This is my patient entity

```
 @Entity
 public class Patient implements java.io.Serializable {

 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
 private Integer id;

 private String firstName;
 private String lastName;

 @OneToMany
 private List<Status>status=new ArrayList<Status>();


public List<Status> getStatus() {
    return status;
 }

 public void setStatus(List<Status> status) {
    this.status = status;
 }

public Patient() {
}

public Integer getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return this.firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return this.lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}


}
```

This is my status entity

```
@Entity
public class Status {


@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer id;


 private String status;


@Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
private Date date;


public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}



public Date getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(Date date) {
    this.date = date;
}


public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

}
```

Now you can see there  is common field "status" in both entity Doctor and patient.Now if i persist table "Doctor" and "Patient" two tables are created "doctor_status"  and "patient_status".But i want a common table where doctors_id and patient_id will be represented by a single column and another column will be status_id.How can i do that?

Comment: You really don't want that. That would make it impossible to know if a row of that common table refers to a doctor or a patient. You wouldn't be able to add a foreign key constraint on this common column. And you won't be able to add a unicity constraint on the status/id tuple either.

Comment: so do i have to create two different table like "doctor_status" and "patient_status"?or is there any better solution?

Comment: Yes, you should do that.